# jquery shorten length of number (convert megabytes to gigabytes)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm converting value from MB to GB

```
var number = 273;
var new_number = (273 /1024); 
alert(new_number);
```

Result ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxpx5qa3/)):

```
this alerts (0.2666015625)
```

How can I shorten this value to 0.26 instead of the long string?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`.toFixed()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) (if you don't mind the fact that the number is rounded).

```
var new_number = (273 /1024).toFixed(2); 
alert(new_number); // 0.27
```

Comment: op wants 0.26 (without rounding)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Math.floor(new_number * 100) / 100
```